# Outlook: Dynamic inbox? Live inbox? Filtered inbox?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, inbox

After searching for bit without success, I suppose it's that I can't find the right terminology for this outlook feature I remember setting up years ago.

I set up criteria for items that would go into a separate inbox. But the email I set up criteria for would be in the main inbox too. If an email is deleted in one folder, the other is deleted too, likewise if I archive in the main inbox, it would be archived in this dynamic folder. What I am trying to achieve with this is a way to have two ways to get to messages and see messages from designated senders in the main inbox or this new dynamic folder. That is, I want to see the email in both folders, but if action is taken on it in either place, it won't need to be done again for the other folder.

To be clear, I don't believe this is a rule that directs mail to another folder that moves it or copies it.

How can I set up this feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I set up criteria for items that would go into a separate inbox.

Do you mean that you create a search folder？ If so, this is the expected behavior. Because search folder is seen only about message filtering, instead of moving a copy of the message into the Search folder.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!